# Handwritten character template matching in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, template-matching

Working with **template matching** of handwritten data input but face some problems for being very new in Matlab. I want to match this template
[image]
with this one..
[image]

So far i did is:

```
function result=test(image1,image2)
%*********************************************************

    image1=rgb2gray(image1);
    image2=rgb2gray(image2);

% check which one is target and which one is template using their size

if size(image1)>size(image2)
    Target=image1;
    Template=image2;
else
    Target=image2;
    Template=image1;
end

% find both images sizes
[r1,c1]=size(Target);
[r2,c2]=size(Template);
% mean of the template
image22=Template-mean(mean(Template));

%corrolate both images
M=[];
for i=1:(r1-r2+1)
    for j=1:(c1-c2+1)
        Nimage=Target(i:i+r2-1,j:j+c2-1);
        Nimage=Nimage-mean(mean(Nimage));  % mean of image part under mask
        corr=sum(sum(Nimage.*image22));
        %warning off
        M(i,j)=corr/sqrt(sum(sum(Nimage.^2)));
    end 
end
% plot box on the target image
result=plotbox(Target,Template,M);
```

For plotbox..

```
function result=plotbox(Target,Template,M)

%*********************************************************
[r1,c1]=size(Target);
[r2,c2]=size(Template);

[r,c]=max(M);
[r3,c3]=max(max(M));

i=c(c3);
j=c3;
result=Target;
for x=i:i+r2-1
   for y=j
       result(x,y)=255;
   end
end
for x=i:i+r2-1
   for y=j+c2-1
       result(x,y)=255;
   end
end
for x=i
   for y=j:j+c2-1
       result(x,y)=255;
   end
end
for x=i+r2-1
   for y=j:j+c2-1
       result(x,y)=255;
   end
end
```

And for testing i use..

```
% read Template image
im1=imread('C:\Users\Shuvro\Desktop\New folder\1.jpg');
% read Traget Image
im2=imread('C:\Users\Shuvro\Desktop\New folder\2.jpg');
% apply templete matching using power of the image
result1=test(im1,im2);
figure,
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(im1);title('Template');
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(im2);title('Target');
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(result1);title('Matching Result using tmp');
```

But this code often can't identify that template in the source image,not understanding what wrong was there.Anybody can help?
Basically when i input 2 images to the system,i want to make their height similar.Then i want to measure template image width and then i want to scan the source image according to that width and examine pixel values.When those pixel values of template will match with source image over 70% then i will give the result that it is found,otherwise not found.
This is what i am thinking to do this.Highly appreciated if anybody can help with above code by editing it or giving suggestions.

Comment: You should probably take a look at image registration

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to warn you that `size(image1)>size(image2)` is a vector comparison, usually you will not want to do it like that. (Perhaps with `all` or `any`).

That being said:

In this specific case the only way to figure out why your code doesn't do what you expect is to load inputs that it should match but doesn't. Then step through the code line by line untill you see any behavior that is unexpected.

---

Of course you could also just try to search for pattern matching functions for matlab, there should be some that you can find on google, or perhaps even on stackoverflow.